# Getting Started with Azure Question

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to get up-and-going with Windows Azure. I understand that I need to create a "Storage Account". However, what I'm confused about is, how I should set it up. For instance, my Azure subscription is set to my company name. I intend to have multiple ASP.NET web applications (web roles) associated with my subscription. Each web application will have its own database.

My question is, should each web application have its own storage account? Or should only one storage account be used for all of my projects?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one way to answer this, but here are some thoughts to help your decision:

- Each storage account is limited to 100TB. If you feel that you will push the limits of this across multiple websites, then create multiple storage accounts for sure.
- To make billing easier, I'd suggest separate storage accounts
- Storage accounts have an SLA of a few thousand transactions per second across the entire storage account. For performance purposes, it's probably better to have separate storage accounts
- Consider putting your diagnostic data in a separate storage account. This way, you can safely give your Storage Account key to a 3rd-party like ParaLeap (creators of [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com)) for monitoring your app, while not giving away the key to real customer data, for instance.
- If you need more than 5 storage accounts, you'll need to contact Customer Support to increase this number.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Storage server is for simple blob storage. This is for when your app needs a file store. Any application, not just Azure web roles, can target a storage service. It's kind of like Amazon S3 if you're familiar with that.

Storage services are not required to run Azure applications. You just need a "compute" instance.

Comment: Azure Storage is not just for simple blob storage. You can use Block Blobs for file storage; You can use Page Blobs for random-access storage and mount NTFS cloud drives; you can use Azure queues; you can use schemaless Azure Tables.

Comment: OP indicated that he/she wanted to "get started" with Azure web roles.  I didn't see any requirements that seemed to indicate Storage Service was necessary.

Comment: Just pointing out that Azure Storage is not just for blobs. Also, when getting started, diagnostics are critical for figuring out what went wrong. And that requires a Storage account.